# Typescript Class and public methods

Tags: typescript, oop

I have a class with a public method, for example:

```
class Foo {
  public firstname: string;
  public lastname: string;
  constructor(firstname:string, lastname:string){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }
  public toString():string {
    return firstname, lastname;
  }
}
export default Foo;
```

I would like call toString method in another class like this:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
...
class Bar {
  ...
  public checkThisMethod(foo:Foo):string {
    ...
    foo.toString();
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

`Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'Foo'.ts(2339)`

What am I doing wrong?

If I create a new Foo object inside checkThisMethod it works, but I don't know why it doesn't work with method arguments.

```
class Bar {
  ...
  public checkThisMethod(foo:Foo):string {
    ...
    let some = new Foo('first','last');
    some.toString(); // It Works!
    ...
    foo.toString(); // Not Works :/
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `Foo` imported into `Bar`'s module?

Comment: can you show the whole code of Bar file (including import)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot include them in the post.

Comment: include the import in the post

Comment: This looks fine (except `toString` which won't compile)..

Comment: Added new comments ...

Comment: Not reproducible..

Comment: The moral of the story is, it's good to remove parts of your code before posting on Stack Overflow so that you have a [mcve], but you should also test yourself whether the issue is still demonstrated after removing part of the code. If it isn't, then you've found the problem yourself and you don't need to ask on Stack Overflow. Since the issue has been resolved due to a simple oversight, I've voted to close.

Comment: You're right I will do it next time. I'm sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproduced, [see example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAcCuAjEAlsNAGYEBOEALgHZgC2ApgFzTXkE0DmA3OlnkLFw1Ok1btOvfsHg122YFXjkAFGUq0GLSdwA00EVvG6uASjQYMVABYEIAOg2jt0ALykKLpnyvRb9g5GYozuhpDGjL7QAL78OPhE-vAAylQc3KpmzKYo-BjkjFTY5DT+do7OkdAA1OWBwdrRcXGooJAwAEJg5ACMeX4JQtDANozAANYAKhUAskU28AAmADwI8AB86ois69m5ln5WhcWlpIgOymkZXFnRGC2obSJdPQBMA1ZDSaPj03MLZYrKbQRgADyojBoSxg6y2JB20Cm+3SUk+R2gJxKZQR8EuqVRmTM91iqDiQA) in Typescript Playground using default config.

```
class Foo {
  public firstname: string;
  public lastname: string;
  constructor(firstname:string, lastname:string){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }
  public toString():string {
    return this.firstname + this.lastname;
  }
}
class Bar1 {
    public checkThisMethod<Foo>(foo: Foo):string {
        return foo.toString();
                 /*^^^^^^^^ Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'Foo'.(2339) */
    }
}
```

`Bar1` like that doesn't work. Replace "Foo" with "T" and the underlying reason may
become more obvious then. The "Foo" is not referring to class above,
but is only a name for type parameter, which in turn can be anything,
and everything doesn't have `.toString` method (e.g. `undefined`),
hence the error.

What you wanted to write, I guess, is a type parameter that can't be
anything but instead can be only "Foo" or be compatible with it.
The correct syntax example `Bar2`:

```
class Bar2 {
    public checkThisMethod<T extends Foo>(foo: T):string {
        return foo.toString();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if the parameterized type `T` is used only once then it is most likely redundant, and thus the same but simpler like `Bar3`:

```
class Bar3 {
    public checkThisMethod(foo: Foo): string {
        return foo.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you're describing occurs at runtime, the question was regarding types...

Comment: @aleksey-l thanks for pointing it out! Answer overhauled based on new info from OP.